# Outlook credentials asked all time

Tags: outlook

I use outlook 2013.

When I open it a pop up window ask for the username and password for the server. I press ok and tick the window Save this password in you password list but it is not working and the pop up window appears again. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: @Roy any help with this?

Comment: Sure thing. When it's happened to me it's either _incorrect password_, or if you are using two-stage authentication (Google Authenticator app), you may need to generate an _app password_ for Outlook.  https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en.  If you have that turned on, don't log in using your regular gmail password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

This is an answer based on my comment above

---

When it's happened to me it's either **incorrect password**, or if you are using **two-stage authentication** (via *Google Authenticator* app for [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/google-authenticator/id388497605?mt=8) or [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en))

> Google Authenticator works with 2-Step Verification for your Google Account to provide an additional layer of security when signing in.

You may need to [generate an app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for Outlook.

> An App password is a 16-digit passcode that gives an app or device permission to access your Google Account. If you use 2-Step-Verification and are seeing a “password incorrect” error when trying to access your Google Account, an App password may solve the problem. Most of the time, you’ll only have to enter an App password once per app or device, so don’t worry about memorizing it.

If you have that turned on, **don't log in using your regular gmail password** but rather the password generated by the app for the app, in this case *Outlook*.